# R: Using ellipsis with a function that takes a arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

Many a times, I find myself typing the following

```
print(paste0(val1,',',val2,',',val3)) to print the output from a function with variables separated by a comma.
```

It is handy when I want to copy generate a csv file from the output.

I was wondering if I can write a function in R that does this for me. With many attempts, I could only get to this the following.

```
ppc <- function(string1,string2,...) print(paste0(string1,',',string2,',',...,))
```

It works well for at the maximum of three arguments.

```
> ppc(1,2,3)
[1] "1,2,3"
> ppc(1,2,3,4)
[1] "1,2,34"
```

`ppc(1,2,3,4)` should have given `"1,2,3,4"`. How can I correct my function? I somehow believe that this is possible in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write your own function.  You can do this with `paste`.

```
paste(1:3,collapse=",")
# [1] "1,2,3"
```

Comment: Realized I do not need to write any separate function for this. It was a silly question...

Answer (score 1):

Or, in case you insist on a `ppc()` function:

```
ppc <- function(...) paste(...,sep=",")
ppc(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: I wrote `printSepbyComma <- function(...) print(paste(...,sep=','))`